# How do I open .SPF file format for Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, file-format, file-conversion

Does anyone know how I can open an `.SPF` format file? I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.5).

I believe it is an image as the person who sent it, sent a scanned document. I tried Photoshop with no success, and Google hasn’t been the biggest help either.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe it is an image as the person who sent it, sent a scanned
>   document.

You saying it’s a scanned document and based on what I am seeing [here on the U.S. Library of Congress Digital Preservation site](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000019.shtml) as well as here on [File-Extensions.org](http://www.file-extensions.org/spf-file-extension) I believe this is a SPIFF (Still Picture Interchange File Format) file:

> This file format enables JPEG and JBIG (bitonal) bitstreams to be
>   exchanged between a wide variety of platforms and applications.

Seems to be a JPEG container. So my first, “brute force” method of attempting to open the file would be to make a copy of the file and just change the extension to `.jpg`. But past that unsure.

I suggest downloading [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/) and seeing if can open it. Also, the developers of GraphicConverter are quite responsive to end user requests so might want to drop them a note about this file-format and see what they say about it.